# How could I simulate jQuery's remove() method with plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this line of code:

```
$('.js-cover-menu-dropdown > li > ul').remove();
```

Which I use to remove every `ul` from the `li`'s of .js-cover-menu-dropdown.

I was wondering how I could re-write this using vanilla JS.

Comment: One way would be to [viewing the unminified jQuery](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js) and look for the remove function, and see how it works.

Comment: What is the purpose of re-writing `.remove()`?

Comment: @guest271314, at a guess, the OP may want to avoid actually requiring the library, or it may be a homework assignment, or they may want to build similar functionality into their own library. Who can guess?

Comment: @guest271314 It's interesting that you ask this, I don't think it deserves an edit, but it's good for here: I had this script. Script was just "take from menu, append to new item in the menu, create dropdown". It was originally in jQuery. I followed basic / optimized (cache selectors, etc) coding standards. Script went from ~8-9ms to 1ms consistent. Now, why do I care? Render time. Many people focus so much on writing maintainable code, which I get, but render times are awful. Every time I see a heavy JS site, I wanna die due to its render time.

Comment: That is a rational reason. Using jQuery alone does not correspond to writing maintainable code. From perspective here, including comments in the code itself as to what the code is trying to achieve and attaching a README to the code base, if possible, would lend to code maintenance for yourself and others whom might utilize your code.

Comment: No, what I am doing is I the heavy-render functions that are for front-end and mostly static (not a lot), in pure JS and try to optimize as best as my knowledge allows, then just the main pieces that don't deal with rendering front-end and don't impact the product for the users directly in jQuery for easiness and all the other benefits. I think people really don't realize how rendering time is the most important factor in your product's success. CDNs and common sense solve most performance hogs for load times, but there's nothing for render time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.js-cover-menu-dropdown > li > ul')
  .forEach(node => node.remove());
```

Comment: Isn't this assuming ECMA 6?

Comment: Note that this is ES6, which is not supported in older IE versions (11 and previous)

Comment: Not saying it is wrong, I just think you should maybe mention it.

Comment: @cale_b Why would anyone be using ie<11?

Comment: The question isn't "why", the question is "do they", and the answer is yes: https://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php - over 3% use IE11.  If you're OK leaving 3% in the dust for the privelidge of writing this as an arrow function instead of a ES5 compliant function, then more power to you.

Comment: @cale_b Interestingly there are rarely if any mentions of the code at reactjs questions not being ES5. Would suggest to that 3% to, if possible, use a FOSS (FLOSS) browser.